# Mean of Date variable data

Tags: curated-data, data-structures, data-format, data-acquisition

I have hourly registered data as :

```
Sort[Join @@ data[[All, 3 ;;]][[All, All, 2 ;; 3]]]
output={{{2013, 6, 19, 12, 0, 0.}, 7980.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 13, 0, 0.}, 
7994.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 14, 0, 0.}, 7860.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 15, 0, 0.}, 
7722.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 16, 0, 0.},  7602.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 17, 0, 0.}, 
7479.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 18, 0, 0.}, 7354.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 19, 0, 0.}, 
7319.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 20, 0, 0.}, 7347.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 21, 0, 0.}, 
7071.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 22, 0, 0.}, 6928.}, {{2013, 6, 19, 23, 0, 0.}, 6854.}, 
{{2013, 6, 20, 0, 0, 0.},6559.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 1, 0, 0.}, 6145.}, 
{{2013, 6, 20, 2, 0,0.}, 5920.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 3, 0, 0.}, 5686.}, 
{{2013, 6, 20, 4, 0, 0.},5696.}, 
{{2013, 6, 20, 5, 0, 0.}, 5901.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 6, 0, 0.},
6684.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 7, 0, 0.}, 7368.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 8, 0, 0.},
7699.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 9, 0, 0.}, 7884.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 10, 0, 0.}, 
7958.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 11, 0, 0.},{ 7984.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 12, 0, 0.}, 
7930.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 13, 0, 0.}, 7792.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 14, 0, 0.}, 
7588.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 15, 0, 0.}, 7479.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 16, 0, 0.}, 
7349.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 17, 0, 0.},  7253.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 18, 0, 0.}, 
7171.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 19, 0, 0.}, 7106.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 20, 0, 0.}, 
7044.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 21, 0, 0.}, 6711.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 22, 0, 0.}, 
6647.}, {{2013, 6, 20, 23, 0, 0.}, 6648.}}
```

I want to have the mean of the each day and the same time consequences just exclude the hours.Could you please help on the code.

Comment: If you would provide some actual sample data, it will be so much more convenient for other to help. Some more detail on what you have tried already and how exactly your result should look like will do so, too.

Comment: @YvesKlett I added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

Since you didn't provide any random data, here's some (with modifications for the 26th of each month):

```
dd = Sort@
Table[{{2004, RandomInteger[{1, 12}], RandomInteger[{1, 31}], 
   RandomInteger[{0, 24}], 0, 0.}, RandomInteger[{10, 50}]}, 
  {n, 0, 2000}] /. 
  {{2004, mn_, 26, h_, m_, s_}, n_} ->  {{2004, mn, 26, h, m, s}, 1000};
```

...

```
{{{2004, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0.}, 50}, 
 {{2004, 1, 1, 18, 0, 0.}, 24},
 {{2004, 1, 1, 20, 0, 0.}, 18}},
 ...
```

Collect the data:

```
days = Gather[dd, 
   DateString[First@#1, "DateShort"] == 
   DateString[First@#2, "DateShort"] &];
```

Compile the totals:

```
dt = Table[
    {days[[x, 1, 1, 1 ;; 3]], Total[days[[x, All, 2]]]}, 
  {x, 1, Length[days]}];
```

...

```
{{{2004, 1, 1}, 92}, 
 {{2004, 1, 1}, 79}, 
 {{2004, 1, 3}, 118},
 ...
```

See if the 26th is showing:

```
DateListPlot[dt, Joined -> True, Filling -> Bottom, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black]]
```

It looks like it might work.

From here, the means should be easy.

[image: datelistplot]

Comment: Many thanks.and very nice gavater.I saw the code as well.Frankly how long does it take for me to write such thing?!!!

Comment: @alex Should take about two minutes typing, but [copy/paste](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KnotData.html) is quicker... :)

Comment: I know but Skills I mean.How long have you been coding?

Comment: @alex [my first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860616/photo-mosaic-in-mathematica-an-example-from-2008-doesnt-work-in-mathematica-8)! but I'm a slow learner...

Comment: that is nice.great.But I think you did well and you were good not slow.Your background is in programming?

Comment: @alex I'm not a programmer or a mathematician, but Mathematica beguiles me... :)